# Get data between specific set of months in SAS PROC SQL

Tags: oracle, sas, proc-sql

I have a dataset where the date is in the 20-JUN-23 format. I want to filter the data such that I can get all the data between 1-MAR-23 and 30-APR-23. If current month is 6 then I want data between 3rd and 4th month. When we enter July (7th month), I want data between April (4th Month) and May (5th Month) and so on. Basically whenever I run the code it gives me data between 3 and 2 months before the current month. I am using SAS PROC SQL (SQL is Oracle is that matters).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SAS solution uses INTNX and assumes your date is a variable in a SAS date format (numeric with date format).

```
proc sql;
create table want as
select * 
from have
where date between intnx('month', date, -3, 'b') and intnx('month', date, -2, 'e');
quit;
```

Answer (score 2):

In Oracle SQL, you can `TRUNC`ate the current date to the start of the month and then use `ADD_MONTHS` to go back a number of months to specify your date range:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  date_column >= ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM'), -3)
AND    date_column <  ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM'), -1)
```